# why does the for-loop not care about the way of increment?

Tags: php, for-loop, increment

This is propably a farcical "problem" but I just don't see the reason for this behaviour.

---

Facts:

```
$i++;
```

returns the current value and then increments $i by one.

```
++$i;
```

increments $i by one and then returns $i.

---

Situations:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i){
    echo $i."\n";
}
```

gives

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

2nd:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    echo $i."\n";   
}
```

gives also

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

---

If I'd take the documentation of the increment literally, I would explain the loops as follows:

1. at the end of each iteration, $i is incremented by one and then
   returned, so we've got at first a 0 because $i started as 0, then a 1 etc.
2. at the end of each iteration, $i is returned and THEN incremented,
   which would, exactly, mean that there were two iterations where $i =
   0.

It's a fact that this is not true. Could somebody please explain, why?

Comment: The action always happens at the end of the loop. It doesn't matter if you post-increment or pre-increment, think of it as a statement all on its own at the end.

Comment: Many thanks to your answers, it turns out that I was really stuck on the difference between setting a statement and returning something. That should be also the reason why $i+2 instead of $i=$i+2 does not work in this part of the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$i` is not being *returned*, it is being *used* (by you). Big difference.

If you were to rewrite your `if` statements to instead use a `while` loop, you'd have these:

**Post-increment**:

```
$i = 0;

while ( $i < 10 ) {
    echo $i."\n";
    $i++;
}
```

**Pre-increment:**

```
$i = 0;

while ( $i < 10 ) {
    echo $i."\n";
    ++$i;
}
```

As you can see, there's no difference between the two.

---

Here's what the 3 statements you supply to the for loop are for:

1. Run before *the first* step
2. Run before *every* step (use the returned value to determine whether to continue with the loop)
3. Run *after* every step

at no point is the returned value of the 3rd statement being utilized in any way.

---

**P.S.** As mentioned, the third statement is run after *every* loop **including the last one**. This is evident by accessing the `$i` variable after the loop has completed:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo $i."\n";
}
echo $i;
```

which would list all the numbers up to **and including** 10.

See it here in action: http://viper-7.com/Y6N2jU

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, the `for` loop checks the condition in the second parameter before executing the third parameter. This means that, in both cases:

- `$i` is initialized with value 0 (this step is obviously skipped for every subsequent iteration);
- `$i` is compared with 10 (it's smaller); and *then*
- `$i` is incremented.

In that last step, whether the value of `$i` is returned before or after the increment shouldn't matter, because the "returned" value of `$i` isn't actually used in any comparison. The actual value of `$i` as stored in memory has still been incremented by one each iteration, after the comparison has been made.

Comment: I think your answer got a bit convoluted. For loops: 1. Initialize 2. Compare, Run 3. Increment. So no matter if you post or pre-increment it happens after the loop code was run and before the next comparison.

Comment: @Rawr Yeah, probably. But what can I say? I'm just a convoluted person.

Comment: I like your answer the best though because it actually listed the for loop stages. But then I read the last paragraph and I'm like whattt?

Answer (score 1):

A for loop has 3 components:

1. An initialization component (the code before the first ';')
2. A termination condition (the code between the first ';' and the second ';')
3. An increment (after the second ';')

The order of execution of these 3 pieces of code is:

- (1) executed **only once** at the beginning of the for loop
- (2) verified **before** each iteration
- (3) executed **after** each iteration

Consequently it's not important if you use the prefix or postfix form of the increment operation; after each iteration the increment (3) will be executed and you will get a new value of the incremented variable

This:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $a = $i++){
    echo $i."\n";
}
```

as compared to this

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $a = ++$i){
    echo $i."\n";
}
```

would make a difference in the value of $a after each iteration, but not in the value of $i

Answer (score 0):

Post-incrementing or Pre-incrementing a variable as the third expression in the loop doesn't have an effect on the behavior of it

Because, `$i++` and `++$i` would both execute at the end of each iteration of the loop.

Comment: He knows that, he is asking "**WHY?**"

Answer (score 0):

If you write the for loop out as a sequence of if statements, I think it would make more sense as to why $i increments each time.

```
i = 0
if i > 10
    return
else
    print i
    i++ // or ++i
if i > 10
    return
else
    print i
    i++ // or ++i
```

and so on.